# Psexec or WMI - new session every time?

Tags: wmi, psexec

Does someone know if if I run PSEXEC (or WMI) N times in the same program - does it open N new sessions? Or does it use the same session over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will open a new session for every time you run it. (Well, unless you were somehow tricking it into running more than one command at a time with a command line like `cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns & echo DONE`... but that is rather unlikely.)

Comment: lots of thanks.

both WM and Psexec open new sessiosn?
How do you know for sure? (I could google the answer...)
Do you have a link for me? That would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure I could find a link explaining it, but you could prove it in a moment by running a simple batch file with multiples of the same command... If you check `netstat -bov` (or similar) after running it, you will see 3 separate sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can check all session openings in the Windows Event Viewer > Security. I was wondering why I had so many session openings and WMIC was the answer.